# How to disable Blazor server side pre-render?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

To disable server side pre-render on asp.net core preview 3, you just needed to comment `@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyApp>())`.

Since asp.net core preview 4, when you comment this line, the page doesn't render and on the main component `@page "/"`, the tag `<app>` remains blank.

So, how can we disable server side pre-render ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution by cores-system in github
Source: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9584#issuecomment-485257261

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapBlazorHub().AddComponent<App>(selector: "app");
   endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); // or - endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

Hope this works...

Comment: Additional informations:
1) Add the index.html inside wwwroot folder
2) Remover `<base href="~/" />` from the html

Answer (score 5):

According to MS Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#handle-prerendering

To disable prerendering, open the `Pages/_Host.cshtml` file and change the `render-mode` attribute of the Component Tag Helper to Server:
CSHTML

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
```

Prerendering of  content is disabled in Pages/_Layout.cshtml:
CSHTML

```
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="Server" />
```