# Params are being sent again after EventCallback is triggered/invoked

Tags: razor, blazor

When using EventCallback in my component, the params for the control are sent again / not updated correctly.

## Component

```
<button @onclick="@(e => ChangePlaceholder())">Change Placeholder</button>
<button @onclick="@(e => ChangePlaceholderEvent())">Change Placeholder Event</button>
<label>@Placeholder</label>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Placeholder { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnChanged { get; set; }

    private void ChangePlaceholder()
    {
        Placeholder = "hello";
    }

    private void ChangePlaceholderEvent()
    {
        Placeholder = "hello";

        OnSelectedChanged.InvokeAsync(Placeholder);
    }
}
```

## Parent Page

```
<Control Placeholder="something" OnChanged=@UpdateSomething />

@code {    
    static void UpdateSomething(string someString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Event went kablam: {someString}");
    }
}
```

If you were to run the **ChangePlaceholder()** function then the UI updates and changes the say **'hello'**, but if you run the **ChangePlaceholderEvent()** function, the label goes back to **'something'** which is the string that the Placeholder param is sent in the first place.

This leads me to believe that EventCallback being triggered also makes the other params for the control to be sent again.

How can I stop the params being sent again?

Edit: I made a webassemby app and tested the same code and the same bug is occurring.

Comment: Is this using Server-side pre-rendering perchance? It could be that

Comment: It is, can I change it to something else?

Comment: You can turn off pre-rendering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764183/how-to-disable-blazor-server-side-pre-render

Comment: @Quango Is there something I need to include for that solution to work? `ComponentEndpointConventionBuilder` does not contain a definition for `.AddComponent<App>(selector: "app")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Event callbacks will trigger a re-render of the parent component and
>   you are unconditionally passing down "something" which is what is
>   causing "something" to be re-rendered.
>
> The problem here is that you are using a parameter as state for your
>   component, which you should avoid.
>
> [Reference](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20756)

You could get around your problem by using 'Action' instead of 'EventCallback':

```
[Parameter]
public Action<string> OnChanged { get; set; }

@code {
    private void ChangePlaceholderEvent()
    {
        Placeholder = "hello";

        OnChanged(Placeholder);
    }
}
```