# Radzen Datagrid seems to be loading twice

Tags: c#, datagrid, blazor, radzen

I have a radzen datagrid on a Blazor Server side app, that seems to be loading twice, this is, when first opening the page all data flashes for half a second (I took a screenshot, the data is show, not a blank grid) and then it switched to loading a it takes about 2 seconds and then shows the content of the grid.

I have been using as per radzen examples the "IsLoading" property to fill up data, I'll put an abridged version of the datagrid and of my code to show what I have.

Razor section:

```
@page "/projectlist"
@page "/"



@inject ISqlData _db
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

@if (IsDetail == true)
{
    <ProjectDetail OnDetailShown="UpdateDetailView" CalendarPeriod="CalendarPeriod" Project="Project"></ProjectDetail>
}
else
{
    <h3><p class="text-center ">Project List</p></h3>

    <RadzenPanel Style="width: calc(100vw - 80px)">
        <RadzenDataGrid style="height: calc(100vh - 175px)" AllowPaging="true" AllowColumnResize="true" PageSize="20"  IsLoading="IsLoading" AllowSorting="true" ShowPagingSummary="true" AllowColumnReorder="true"  AllowMultiColumnSorting="true"  AllowFiltering="true" FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" Data="@Projects" TItem="Project" >
            <Columns>
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Project" Property="ProjectNumber" Title="Project Number" Sortable="false" FilterOperator="FilterOperator.Contains"  Width="130px" Pickable="false" Frozen="true"  >
                    <Template Context="data"><RadzenButton Click=@(args => OnClick(data.ProjectId, data.ProjectStatus)) Shade="Shade.Dark" Text="@data.ProjectNumber" Size="ButtonSize.Small" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Success" /></Template>
                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Project" Property="Name" Title="Project Name" MinWidth="300px"  />
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Project" Property="ContractType" Title="Contract Type"  MinWidth="300px" />
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Project" Property="PtdUnbilled" Title="Beginning WIP Balance" FormatString="{0:0,0.00}"  TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" MinWidth="210px"   Width="210px"  />
            </Columns>
        </RadzenDataGrid>
    </RadzenPanel>
}
```

and Code section:

```
    public IEnumerable<Project> Projects;
    private Employee Employee { get; set; } = null!;
    private string PersonnelNo { get; set; } = null!;
    public string EmployeeAdName { get; set; }
    public CalendarPeriod CalendarPeriod { get; set; } = null!;
    public IEnumerable<ProjectWip> ProjectWipCalculations { get; set; }
    public bool IsDetail { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoading { get; set; }
    
    
    protected override async Task  OnParametersSetAsync()
    {

    }

    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        IsLoading = true;


        EmployeeAdName = (await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User.Identity!.Name!;
        CalendarPeriod = await _db.GetCalendarPeriodAsync();
        
        Employee = await _db.GetEmployeeDataAsync(EmployeeAdName);

        PersonnelNo = Employee.PersonnelNumber;

        Projects = await _db.GetProjectsAsync(PersonnelNo);

        var enumerable = Projects.ToList();
        var projectList = enumerable.Select(x => x.ProjectId).ToArray();

        ProjectWipCalculations = await _db.GetCurrentMonthWIPData(projectList, CalendarPeriod.PeriodFrom);

        foreach (var project in enumerable)
        {
            var projectWip = ProjectWipCalculations.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectId == project.ProjectId);
            if (projectWip != null)
            {
                project.CurrMonthInvoiceTotal = projectWip.CurrMonthInvoiceTotal;
            }
        }
        IsLoading = false;
    }

    private void OnClick(int projectId, string projectStatus)
    {
        IsDetail = true;
        Project = Projects.First(x => x.ProjectId == projectId);
        Project.ProjectStatus = projectStatus;
    }

    private void UpdateDetailView()
    {
        IsDetail = false;
    }
```

If I remove the "IsLoading" property the only difference is that the grid flashess for half a second all filled and then it blanks for about 2 seconds and the is shown, the "IsLoading" just renders an animation in the middle for a bit.

I don't entirely understand what is happening, if maybe the grid is being filled and then the call is done again to fill it? (I have all code in `OnInitializedAsync`

I've added a small gif showing what I mean below
[image]

Comment: Do you have any other code that changes the `Projects` property?

Comment: Some suggestions: Look at using `LoadData` parameter so that you can filter your data using database queries, which is a massive performance increase if you have a lot of pages, and should also resolve your flickering issue. Look for `Data Binding -> LoadData event` in their documentation. Also, for better display, use the `Template` `RenderFragement` to display the project detail within your table. Look for `Hierarchy` in their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not a radzen thing.
Is because blazor, loads twice.
That is because blazor first prerenders the page to show the user, and then loads the full page.
If you want to disable this you can disable prerender of the blazor app.

[How to disable Blazor server side pre-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764183/how-to-disable-blazor-server-side-pre-render)

The other solution is setting onload grid property to true by defaultt , and then in the event onAfterRender method if is first render set loading to false.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use OnAfterRnderAsync()

```
protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender == true)
        {
            ReloadChart();
        }
        return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
```

Comment: how would I use this? what is the "ReloadChart()"? this instead of the OnInitializedAsync?

Comment: Here's a link to some documentation about the lifecycle of a Blazor Component that might be useful.  Make sure you're wiring your data fetching in at the right cycle.  

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0

From your video, it's hard to tell, but, you can always put breakpoints in to see which lifecycle event is being triggered when.

Answer (score -1):

Try using fields instead of properties in general to avoid triggering parameter set events.

Also, a trick i use in my projects is to initialize task-fields using ??= then await them. That prevents the method to fire twice.

Edit: Added code example

```
private Task? _doSomethingTask;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _doSomethingTask ??= DoSomethingAsync(_arg);
    await _doSomethingTask;
}
```